# Failed rmRF: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink .bowerrc

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, bower

I am using TFS Online todo Continuous Integration The builds pass but the Release fail because I get the following error

```
Unhandled: Failed rmRF: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\path\.bowerrc'
```

The thing I did notice is that when i look at the files in TFS i can see the .bowerrc but once artifacts gets dropped after the build and i look at the Zip file the .bowerrc is not their is that possibly the reason

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue in VSTS today. The error was :

```
##[error]Unhandled: Failed rmRF: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\...\UI\app.js'
```

This error was thrown in the copy step of my build definition. I just cleaned up the existing files in that path and the build was successful. You may even consider to have the "Overwrite" option turned on if you faces the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=".bowerrc" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to the csproj file

Answer (score 0):

If your VM is Windows, put your services in other folder, not in `C:\` directly.
For example, in `C:\Services\path\.bowerrc`.